# How to mark the end of a certain unit (remark, definition, ...) in the text?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Oftentimes it is useful to explicitly mark the end of a definition, remark, or any other logical unit in the text. This can be done by typographical tricks like font changes (italics are common for theorems) or additional vertical whitespace. However, this in my experience lacks the clarity provided by an explicit end marker.

The most frequent use of the [Tombstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_%28typography%29) appears to be for marking the end of a proof. In [this book](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-658-06288-0) however, the tombstone is used as an end marker for any numbered (and thus referenceable) unit. I find this an elegant solution. Some people have objected to this since according to them, the tombstone should only be used to mark the end of a proof.

According to Paul Halmos (in "I Want to Be a Mathematician") on the other hand, the tombstone "is used to indicate an end, usually the end of a proof." So it is only *usually* the end of a proof, not always.

Dijkstra uses "(end or remark)" or "(end of proof)".

Could someone please point me to other works that use explicit end markers (or phrases) for certain units in the text?

Comment: Without wanting to search through my textbook collection right now, I can say without examples that I've certainly seen both the tombstone symbol and other symbols like $\large\circ$, $\color{red}{\huge\bullet}$, $\large\blacktriangle$, etc used to indicate the end of a section. $\lozenge$

Comment: Old style books simply used (for end of proofs)  `Q. E. D.`  in small caps, which was quite clear. You also may use the etymological `Ο. Ε. Δ.` ;o)